# Error reading CSV served by nginx

Tags: java, csv, nginx, opencsv

I am using `com.opencsv.CSVReader` to read a CSV from a URL served by my nginx Web server. The CSV file content is exactly this:

`0.999,1.399,1.799,2.199,2.599,2.999,3.399,3.799,4.199,4.599,4.999,5.399`

The problem is that when I read the file I get no csv values:

```
try (InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(new URL(...csv).openStream(), "UTF-8"); CSVReader r = new CSVReader(in)) {

  List<String[]> csv = r.readAll();
  ....
```

After this point, csv has failed to get the data (but no errors are raised), and `csv.get(0).length` is incorrectly `1`, an empty string. I do not know why. Tests that I have done to isolate the problem:

- I have tried obtaining the file via http and https from my nginx with similar results. I must say that this code was working fine not too long ago, and with no apparent reason now it is failing.
- I have used a `BufferedReader` to see what was in `in` before reading the csv and I got:

  ```
  Date: Fri, 10 Aug 2018 03:11:13 GMT
  Content-Type: text/plain
  Content-Length: 71
  Last-Modified: Wed, 12 Jul 2017 16:23:24 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
  ETag: "..."
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
  X-Frame-Options: DENY
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  Accept-Ranges: bytes

  0.999,1.399,1.799,2.199,2.599,2.999,3.399,3.799,4.199,4.599,4.999,5.399
  ```

  So I am not sure if the headers were also read by the csv reader and messed with it somehow.
- I have used the same code to access an external CSV instead of the one served by my nginx and it worked fine, and the test using the `BufferedReader` with the external CSV did not show any header, just the csv values.

That is why I am also considering that it could be an nginx problem, since I also experienced a recent error of files not finishing download and I had to change my previous `keepalive_timeout 65` that was working fine to `keepalive_timeout 0`. I am not sure why this happened all of a sudden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was very hard to debug, but the solution was to reinstall nginx because my copy was corrupted. My nginx instance was sending extra `\r` characters that did not interfere with `curl` or similar but that disrupted the Java implementation.

By the way - This probably highlighted a bug in `.openStream()` implementation.